# Make two characters equivalent in a Python find() call

Tags: python, string, search, find, character

Using Python, I want to search for, for example, `'tune yards'` in a block of text that may say `'tune-yards'` (with a hyphen) and it may say `'tune yards'` (without). I want both to be considered matches. I'm using the `find()` function. Is there a good Pythonic way to treat `-` and spaces as one and the same, instead of just stacking `elif` statements?

Something like this: (I know this doesn't work :P)

```
treating '-' as ' ':
    if blockOfText.find('tune yards') > -1:
        do something
```

Comment: I am trying not to `replace('-', ' ')` the block of text just because that seems sluggish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> re.search('tune[ -]yards', '58 tune yards of music')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1ad68b8>
>>> re.search('tune[ -]yards', '35 tune-yards of trombone')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1ad6988>
```

And match objects are always true (with the other possible returned value being `None`), so the result can be tested via `if`.

Comment: I've been impressed a lot with `re` while learning Python. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if (blockOfText.find('tune yards') + blockOfText.find('tune-yards'))  > -1:
    do something
```

Comment: This will fail to find the text at position 0.

Comment: If the location of the match doesn't matter, find() is inconvenient - use `'tune yards' in blockOfText or 'tune-yards' in blockOfText`.